# AngularJS Material and Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-material

How to create an app with ionic angularJS material?

or using the material framework design lite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try [Ionic Material](http://ionicmaterial.com/). It's meant to blend Google's Material design with Ionic, just as Angular Material is meant to do the same for plain AngularJS.

> Ionic Material is an extension library for the Ionic Framework,
>   meaning you don't need to change the way you develop your Ionic hybrid
>   apps to have them materialized.